# Set theorem counter to be Roman

Tags: theorems, counters

I wanted to make the counter for a theorem displayed as capital roman numerals (I, II, III), but none of these attempts worked

```
\newtheorem{test}[\Roman{counter}]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{test}[Roman]{Theorem}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use:

```
\newtheorem{test}{Theorem}
\renewcommand\thetest{\Roman{test}}
```

Defining a new theorem environment `test` defines a new counter `test`. The optional argument, such as you used, says the ‘test’ environment shares the counter of another theorem-like environment.