# Theorem roman numbering

Tags: theorems

I want to have numbered theorems as theorem I, theorem II, theorem III, etc according to the attached image but I cannot fix it in my code. This is my latex code:

```
‎\documentclass[journal]{journal}‎

‎\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}‎

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}‎‎‎‎[section]

‎\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}‎

‎\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}‎

‎\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}‎
```

This is the picture of the pdf file:

[image]

There is a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216266/set-theorem-counter-to-be-roman) but I do not know how I can use it in my problem.
Template of the journal Latex file is [here](http://www.waset.org/downloads/latex.zip)

Comment: Are you actually using `journal.cls` (`/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paper/journal.cls` on my system) or is that just a placeholder for the journal's actual document class? If so, I would remove the `[section]` at the end of `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`
and add `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\Roman{theorem}}`. That document class also already defines an `example` environment, so defining your own in addition throws an error.

Comment: It can work bout it is not enough. After theorem II, I have example I, bout it compile example III in pdf. The sample of my paper is belong to IEEE and I attached it to the question.

Comment: I have some theorems, definitions and examples in some sections at my paper that they should be numbered by I,II,II,... separately.

Comment: That's a different document class from the one I mentioned. How should examples be numbered? If you want them to have separate numbering then change `\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}` to simply `\newtheorem{example}{Example}`. If you want them to use Roman numerals as well then use `\renewcommand{\theexample}{\Roman{example}}` as well. (Similarly with lemmas if you want them separate.) But it's weird that you're using the journal's own document class and it's not preconfigured to do what they want. Also my output still looks different from yours when using it, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this template.

When you create a new environment theorem-like using

`\newtheorem{<environment name>}{<heading>}`

a  counter with the same name of the environment  will be created. For example

`\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}` will create the counter `definition` and with the command:

`\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\Roman{definition}}`

the example will be numbered with Roman numbers.

Each environment will be numbered consecutively (I, II, III, IV. ...) throughout the document regardless of the others.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[journal]{journal}

%% \newtheorem{<environment name>}{<heading>} a counter with the same name of the enviroment  will be created
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\Roman{theorem}} % Use Roman numbering

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\Roman{definition}}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\Roman{example}}


\begin{document}
    
    \section{Definitions}
    
    \begin{definition}
        Given two line segments whose lengths are \(a\) and \(b\) respectively there is a 
        real number \(r\) such that \(b=ra\).
    \end{definition}
    
    
    \begin{definition}
        Given two line segments whose lengths are \(a\) and \(b\) respectively there is a 
        real number \(r\) such that \(b=ra\).
    \end{definition}

    \section{Theorems}
        
    \begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem about right triangles and can be summarised in the next 
    equation 
    \[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        This is a theorem about right triangles and can be summarised in the next 
        equation 
        \[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
    \end{theorem}
        
    \begin{theorem}
        This is a theorem about right triangles and can be summarised in the next 
        equation 
        \[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
    \end{theorem}

\section{Examples}

    \begin{example}
        There's no right rectangle whose sides measure 3cm, 4cm, and 6cm.
    \end{example}
    
    \begin{example}
        There's no right rectangle whose sides measure 3cm, 4cm, and 6cm.
    \end{example}       


    \section{Final}

    \begin{theorem}
        This is a theorem about right triangles and can be summarised in the next 
        equation 
        \[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{example}
        There's no right rectangle whose sides measure 3cm, 4cm, and 6cm.
    \end{example}

    \end{document}
```